# Selecting rows in order within a range, and the next n rows beyond the range

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a timeseries database with one multicolumn index on series id and time. (I have a db fiddle for this here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMbw46y49xbWcDoLSeWqWo/7 )

Most of the queries are of the form

```
SELECT event_time, event_value
FROM test_events
WHERE series_id=@seriesId
AND event_time>=@lowerBound
AND event_time<=@upperBound
ORDER BY event_time
```

Which seems to work pretty well or with one bound and a LIMIT

```
SELECT event_time, event_value
FROM test_events
WHERE series_id=@seriesId
AND event_time>=@lowerBound
ORDER BY event_time
LIMIT n
```

Where n is a number usually less than 10 - these don't seem to perform quite so well as I'd have hoped for (with many millions of rows)

But now I have a requirement to support a query where I must fetch not only the events within the lower and upper bounds, but also the next n events afterwards.

The best I can come up with is to do a UNION of the above queries - for example:

```
(SELECT event_time,event_data FROM test_events
WHERE series_id = 1
AND event_time >= '20200101T00:00:01Z'
AND event_time < '20200101T00:00:05Z'
ORDER by event_time)
UNION ALL
(SELECT event_time,event_data FROM test_events
WHERE series_id = 1
AND event_time >= '20200101T00:00:05Z'
ORDER by event_time
LIMIT 3); -- could be any number, usually 1-10
```

I also have to do something similar for aggregates, perf there is even worse.

I feel like there must exist a better way of writing this query for performance, but I can't find it. Intuitively I feel like he db should only need to go to the index once in order to get the rows that satisfy the bounds as well as get the next n. I was wondering if there was something I could do with the LEAD function, but that seems to get the next item as a column of the existing results.

I'd appreciate any advice, even if I knew this is as good as it's going to get, then I could stop thinking about it :)